# wsHttpBinding MessageSecurityException after runtime Web.config write update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I am using default `wsHttpBinding` on a **IIS** hosted **WCF** Service.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.MyBehavior" name="WCFService.MyService">
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Common.IMyService" name="WsHttpBinding_MyWCFService">
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

I know it is bad practice but my **WCF** service must update the web.config file.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection;
section.ConnectionStrings["mainConnection"].ConnectionString = newValue;

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataProviderUsername"] = userName;
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataProviderPassword"] = password;

config.Save(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

I am able to do this and my winforms client does get the desired response but an exception is thrown when disposing the client.

```
using (MyClient client = new MyClient(new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(), endpoint))
                        {
                            var result = client.GetResult(myParams);

                            var success=result.succsess;//result correct

                        }//throws on disposing
```

Here is the ServiceModel.Fault exception inside the MessageSecurityException

The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT/Cancel' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

If I don´t update the web.config file no exception is thrown.
Is there a way I can still use the wsHttpBinding and update my web.config file at runtime?

Comment: What are you updating in the configuration file?  The service might be restarting due to the web.config change, so it's causing the abort.  I.e., client connects to WCF service, WCF service updates config file and then gets restarted - previous connection is lost.

Comment: @Tim That could be it. I edited the question to include my web.config runtime changes.

Comment: Why are you setting the connection settings dynamically, any specific reason? Why can't you store directly into the config file?

Comment: @Prakash Kalakoti You mean at design time? So that I can change them at runtime.